# Does magnetism affect corrosion?

Tags: soft-question, electromagnetic-radiation

Supposing there is an iron nail that is left to rust, if we compare the time it takes to rust with that of a magnetized iron nail, will there be any difference in the time of corrosion (assuming other environmental factors are constant)?

Comment: You'll have to keep the iron nail continuously magnetized by keeping it in presence of another magnet(Kind of violates the *"same environment"* condition). Maybe you would want to consider a steel nail.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like magnetization can accelerate corrosion (http://www.ifw-dresden.de/de/institute/institut-fuer-komplexe-materialien/abteilungen/chemie-funktioneller-materialien/corrosion/corrosion-of-permanent-magnet-materials/impact-of-the-magnetization-state-on-the-corrosion-of-ndfeb-permanent-magnets/ ) (I did not look at the references there).